# Why is my WPF Validation Error not getting displayed?

Tags: wpf, validation, controltemplate

I have defined a control template for showing Validation Errors:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"  
                                   Background="Red"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"
        RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}">                                        
                                </Binding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>                                
                        </TextBlock>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder ></AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I have defined a TextBox as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" PreviewTextInput="textBox1_PreviewTextInput"  
      Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" />
```

I am setting the validation from code behind as follows:

```
    private void textBox1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
     ....
     ....

     ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError(new DummyValidator(),
            txtBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty));
        Validation.MarkInvalid(txtBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty), validationError);            
        validationError.ErrorContent = "This is wrong input";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

**Now the problem is The Validation is getting fired and a red strip is shown but the error message inside that is not getting displayed!!
May be I am wrong with this** 
 It is throwing some exception in console (index out of bounds exception)

```
<Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"
        RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}">
```

Please guide me regarding Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"
    RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}">
```

Your RelativeSource is wrong

```
<Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"
    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
```

Comment: I believe its {RelativeSource Self} with a space instead of the period